# Extending a Variable's Length With Random Numbers Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, loops, variable-assignment

I am making an AI that tries to solve a user-inputted "numberle" in JavaScript. I don't want the user to do extra work just to see an AI do it's thing, so on the input field, if the user inputs a number that has less than 5 digits, the JavaScript should add random numbers at the end of the variable, until it has a total of five digits.

I used all the loops I had experience with, under an `if` statement, so if the length of the input was less than 5 (like 3), the loop will add `5 - the number of digits of the input (2)` digits that are random, using the `Math.random` attribute.
Here is the code I currently have:

```
if (input.length < 5) 
   do {
     input = (input * 10) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  } while (input.length < 5);
} 
console.log(input)
```

I have also used the `for` and `while` loops with basically the same condition (obviously modified for the if loop; made a variable for `input.length` so that it has the same value).

Here is what I get in the console:

```
5 // Inputted number (1 digit)
52 // Inputted digit + random number
```

As you can see, the loop only runs once, although it should've ran 3 more times. I am using strict mode also. My code editor is github.dev, and I am using the CodeSwing console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If input is a number, it will not have "length", since it is not a string.

You can achieve the desired result like this:

```js
let input = 5;
let digits = 2;
while (input < 10**(digits-1)) input = ~~((input+Math.random())*10);
console.log(input);
```

Note that `~~` is a compact way of doing `Math.floor()`

Alternatively, without a while loop:

```js
let input = 5, digits = 2, M = Math; L = x=>~~(M.log(x)/M.log(10))+1;
input = ~~((input+M.random())*10**(digits - L(input)));
console.log(input);
```